# ng-packagr on Ionic 3 custom library

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular5, ng-packagr

I need to build a set of libraries for my Ionic app, for reduce the time-to-market and have a sharable pieces of code. I found ng-packagr and i'm tring to figure out how to make it work with Ionic 3.9.5.

During the build phase (running `ng-packagr -p package.json`) i get the following errors

```
BUILD ERROR
node_modules\ionic-angular\components\picker\picker-component.d.ts.PickerCmp.html(13,71): : Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
node_modules\ionic-angular\components\input\input.d.ts.TextInput.html(1,928): : Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
node_modules\ionic-angular\components\input\input.d.ts.TextInput.html(1,961): : Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.

Error: node_modules\ionic-angular\components\picker\picker-component.d.ts.PickerCmp.html(13,71): : Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
node_modules\ionic-angular\components\input\input.d.ts.TextInput.html(1,928): : Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
node_modules\ionic-angular\components\input\input.d.ts.TextInput.html(1,961): : Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.

    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\app_repo\gw-ionic-task-app\task-module\node_modules\ng-packagr\lib\ngc\compile-source-files.js:53:68)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\app_repo\gw-ionic-task-app\task-module\node_modules\ng-packagr\lib\ngc\compile-source-files.js:7:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\app_repo\gw-ionic-task-app\task-module\node_modules\ng-packagr\lib\ngc\compile-source-files.js:3:12)
    at Object.compileSourceFiles (C:\app_repo\gw-ionic-task-app\task-module\node_modules\ng-packagr\lib\ngc\compile-source-files.js:19:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\app_repo\gw-ionic-task-app\task-module\node_modules\ng-packagr\lib\ng-v5\entry-point\ts\compile-ngc.transform.js:26:32)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\app_repo\gw-ionic-task-app\task-module\node_modules\ng-packagr\lib\ng-v5\entry-point\ts\compile-ngc.transform.js:7:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

Seems that `ionic-angular` break the `ng-packagr` build, but i can't get how to fix it.

This is my `package.json`

```
{
 "name": "ionic-task-module",
 "version": "0.0.1",
 "main": "./dist/bundles/ionic-task-module.umd.min.js",
 "module": "./dist/index.js",
 "typings": "./dist/index.d.ts",
 "scripts": {
   "packagr": "ng-packagr -p package.json",
   //other scripts....
 },
 "ngPackage": {
   "lib": {
     "entryFile": "public_api.ts",
   }
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "cpx": "^1.5.0",
   "gulp": "^3.9.1",
   "gulp-inline-ng2-template": "^4.0.0",
   "ng-packagr": "^3.0.0",
   "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
   "renamer": "^0.6.1",
   "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
   "rollup": "^0.58.2",
   "typescript": ">=2.4.2 <2.5",
   "uglify-js": "^2.7.5"
 },
 "dependencies": {
   "@angular/animations": "^5.2.11",
   "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
   "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
   "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
   "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
   "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
   "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
   "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
   "@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
   "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
   "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
   "@ionic-native/core": "~4.20.0",
   "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
   "ionic-angular": "3.9.5",
   "ionicons": "3.0.0",
   "intl": "1.2.5",
   "moment": "^2.24.0",
   "ngx-countdown-timer": "^0.1.9",
   "lokijs": "1.5.6",
   "rxjs": "5.5.11",
   "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
   "zone.js": "0.8.29",
   "localforage": "1.7.2",
   "ol": "5.3.3"
 }
}
```

In `public_api.ts` i just export my main module.
Its maybe related to a wrong version of `packagr`? (v3.0.6 is the last version compatible with Angular 5.x)

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Developing a Angular Library isn't a easy task.

I would recommend you to use a tool like nrwl/nx: https://nx.dev/angular

Or if it should be more cross platform with angular this could be a pretty cool helper: https://nstudio.io/xplat/

---

But you can do it also on your own, but here i would also recommend you to change your workplace setup.

1. Create a new project with `ng new my-workplace --application=false`
2. Add your library `ng add library my-lib`
3. Add your applications `ng add application my-app`

The CLI setups in this case a lot for you... but when you wan't to do it manually you can also change your angular.json according to the cli template. To do that create a dummy workplace like above and change the configs according to it.

For Library Dev there are a lot of things to know:

1. When you use barell exports/imports then only use it with `my-folder/index` the /index is very important for ng-packager, otherwise it won't work
2. Export every Component you want to use from external to the public_api.ts, for this you can export them one by one or like in point 1 with barell exports, but keep  in mind to export it with /index...
3. If you want also library styles then you have to build them manually with build-scss and copy it to your dist folder
4. avoid circular dependency errors